# How can I determine what's making my partials render so slowly?

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-3.1, profiling

I'm working on an application that has to render a very large page, composed from a bunch of partials. I can see the rendering time for each of my partials in the log, and there are several that take more than 500 milliseconds.

Obviously, this is unacceptable. **How can I profile the rendering of these partials**? For instance, how can I get a breakdown of the methods being called within them and say, "Oh, I'm spending X milliseconds on Y uses of `link_to`", etc.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2-p290 (I can use 1.9.3 if that's helpful) and Rails 3.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the ruby_prof gem for this.

Install the gem and then setup an around_filter that looks like this

```
def log_profile
  result =RubyProf.profile do
    yield
  end

  File.open(Rails.root.join("profile.html"),"w") do |out|
    printer = RubyProf::GraphHtmlPrinter.new(result)
    printer.print(out,:min_percent=>0)
  end
end
```

This will dump a profile of the action into profile.html, for you to examine. Ruby prof has a bunch of output formatters you can play with. Remember to do this with cache_classes on - you don't want class reloading obscuring your view

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I'm can see the HTML graph, but I don't understand it. Do you know of any reference on this?

Comment: Hmmm, this helps some. http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/files/examples/flat_txt.html